# Spring mvc 4 can't render jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC 4 without using the web.xml but instead use the following:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.bookstr.WebConfig");
    return context;
}

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.bookstr.*" })
public class WebConfig {

}
```

For some reason the home.jsp file I have created and placed in the src->main->webapp folder will not be rendered when I use the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("home", "Hello world");

        return "home";
    }
}
```

And the JSP file is the following:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
${home}
</body>
</html>
```

Update!

[image: Folder structure as requested]

Folder structure as requested.

I can see that the HomeController is not getting called.

Comment: Did you register a `ViewResolver` to resolves you jsp views?

Comment: No I have not @AliDehghani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a `ViewResolver` in your `WebConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.bookstr")
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResover = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

This way, when you return the `home` from your controller, it will try to render the `/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp` view. For configuring `DispatcherServlet` programtically, it's easier to use `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. For example, you simply can:

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*.html" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your controller getting called? put a breakpoint in your controller and make sure of that. Also, where did you put your views?

Comment: Register the resolver and create `home.jsp` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`. Also, add the `webapp` folder in marked `src/main`.